CSS Styles not being applied to html page in chrome
I have applied styles by using internal css code, however the styles don't seem to be applied to the html web page in the browser. I have troubleshooted everywhere yet I still cant fix it. Weirdly, the style doesn't show up in inspect element either. I'm just starting out coding, so I have no idea whats the problem. Heres my code:


let balance = 10000;
let stocks = [];

// Function to fetch stock price using Alpha Vantage API
async function getStockPrice(symbol) {
    try {
        const apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY'; // Replace 'YOUR_API_KEY' with your actual Alpha Vantage API key
        const response = await fetch(`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=${symbol}&apikey=${apiKey}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        
        // Extract the latest stock price from the API response
        const latestPrice = parseFloat(data['Global Quote']['05. price']);
        
        return latestPrice;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching stock price:', error);
        return null;
    }
}

function buyStock(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
    const stockSymbol = document.getElementById("stockInput").value.toUpperCase();
    const quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById("quantityInput").value);

    getStockPrice(stockSymbol).then(stockPrice => {
        const totalCost = stockPrice * quantity;

        // Check if the user has enough balance to buy stocks
        if (totalCost <= balance) {
            balance -= totalCost;
            updateBalance();
            updateStockList(stockSymbol, quantity, stockPrice);
            populateSellDropdown(); // Update the sell dropdown after buying stocks
        } else {
            alert("Insufficient balance!");
        }
    });
}

function sellStock(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
    const stockSymbol = document.getElementById("sellStockInput").value.toUpperCase();
    const quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById("sellQuantityInput").value);

    const stockIndex = findStockIndex(stockSymbol);

    if (stockIndex !== -1 && quantity <= stocks[stockIndex].quantity) {
        getStockPrice(stocks[stockIndex].symbol).then(stockPrice => {
            const totalSaleAmount = stockPrice * quantity;

            balance += totalSaleAmount;
            updateBalance();
            updateStockListAfterSale(stockIndex, quantity);
        });
    } else {
        alert("You either entered an invalid stock symbol or don't have enough stocks to sell!");
    }
}

function updateBalance() {
    document.getElementById("balance").innerText = balance.toFixed(2);
}

function updateStockList(symbol, quantity, price) {
    const stockList = document.getElementById("stockList");
    const listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.textContent = `${quantity} shares of ${symbol} at $${price.toFixed(2)} each`;
    stockList.appendChild(listItem);

    // Add the bought stock to the stocks array
    stocks.push({ symbol: symbol, quantity: quantity, price: price });
}

function updateStockListAfterSale(stockIndex, quantitySold) {
    const stockList = document.getElementById("stockList");
    const stockItem = stockList.childNodes[stockIndex];
    const currentQuantity = stocks[stockIndex].quantity;

    if (quantitySold === currentQuantity) {
        stockList.removeChild(stockItem);
        stocks.splice(stockIndex, 1);
    } else {
        stocks[stockIndex].quantity -= quantitySold;
        stockItem.textContent = `${stocks[stockIndex].quantity} shares of ${stocks[stockIndex].symbol} at $${stocks[stockIndex].price.toFixed(2)} each`;
    }
}

function populateSellDropdown() {
    const sellDropdown = document.getElementById("sellStockInput");
    sellDropdown.innerHTML = ""; // Clear previous options

    stocks.forEach((stock, index) => {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = stock.symbol;
        option.textContent = `${stock.quantity} shares of ${stock.symbol}`;
        sellDropdown.appendChild(option);
    });
}

function findStockIndex(symbol) {
    for (let i = 0; i < stocks.length; i++) {
        if (stocks[i].symbol === symbol) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1; // Stock symbol not found
}

document.getElementById("buyForm").addEventListener("submit", buyStock);
document.getElementById("sellForm").addEventListener("submit", sellStock);
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 36px;
}

section {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #222;
    margin: 20px auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
}

form {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

label {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="number"],
button {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    transition: border-color 0.3s ease;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
button:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color: #007bff;
}

button {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #0056b3;
}

#stockList {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

footer {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
<header>
    <h1>Stock Market Simulator</h1>
    <p>Your Balance: $<span id="balance">10000</span></p>
</header>

<section id="buySection">
    <h2>Buy Stocks</h2>
    <form id="buyForm">
        <label for="stockInput">Stock Symbol:</label>
        <input type="text" id="stockInput" placeholder="Enter Stock Symbol" required>
        <label for="quantityInput">Quantity:</label>
        <input type="number" id="quantityInput" placeholder="Quantity" required>
        <button type="submit">Buy</button>
    </form>
</section>

<section id="stockListSection">
    <h2>Your Stocks</h2>
    <ul id="stockList">
        <!-- Bought stocks will be displayed here dynamically -->
    </ul>
</section>

<section id="sellSection">
    <h2>Sell Stocks</h2>
    <form id="sellForm">
        <!-- Sell stocks form will be generated dynamically by JavaScript -->
    </form>
</section>

<footer>
    <p>&copy; 2024 Stock Market Simulator</p>
</footer>



I have tried troubleshooting steps according to both stack and chatgpt but nothing helps

I ran this code myself and all the styling was fine.
JsFiddle

Have you checked your browser's developer tools for errors?

And have you cleared cache?

I tested the code and it worked fine. This commonly happens with out of date browsers or if something in your browser is blocking it. It may help if you try using an external css file for your styles and link it in your code like this
`

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!--Links the style sheet-->
    <title> Your website name </title>
</head>

`
Normally you only do this to make your code cleaner I have had my code do weird stuff like this before where it only works when it is in a separate file like that and vice versa.
